# Returning something that is equal to nothing in an interface

Tags: java, interface

I have been making a Tetris-like game in Java recently, I have a interface IBlocks which goes over `ConsBlock` and `EmptyBlock` (`ConsBlock` is a list with a block at the beginnning and a `IBlock` list at the end, for some reason that's the way my teacher wanted it).

I have the `getfirst()` function in the interface:

```
public interface IBlocks{
//returns the first block in a list of blocks
public Resting getfirst();
```

(A `Resting` is one block in the Game)

Then, in the ConsBlock class, I have:

```
public class ConsBlock implements IBlocks{
//returns the first block in a list of blocks
public Resting getfirst(){
    return this.first;
```

But in the `EmptyBlock` class, I want it to return something that would be similar to saying there isn't one. I tried returning `null`, but that gave me a null pointer exception due to that fact that the function in the interface tells it to return a `Resting`. What would be the best way to represent an empty one without returning a Resting with random numbers?

Comment: can you show the code where the `NullPointerException` occurs?

Comment: The answers below are fine, but you could also just check if `the object == null`.

Comment: @asgs                                                     NullPointerException:                                                                                                   
                                                                           public class EmptyBlock implements IBlocks{                                                                                                //returns the first thing in the list
    public Resting getfirst(){
          return null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface IResting;
public class Resting implements IResting;
```

Then

```
public class EmptyResting implements IResting {
    @Override
    public Object sampleMethod() {
        // return what an empty block ought to return
    }
}
```

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Response to your comment: you still need to do:

```
public class EmptyBlock implements IBlocks {
    @Override
    public IResting getFirst() {
        return new EmptyResting();
    }
}
```

Note that your `IBlocks` and `ConsBlock` classes need to return an `IResting` not a `Resting`

Make sure to read that wiki link!

Comment: I tried putting it into the EmptyBlock, but it returns: *EmptyBlock is not abstract and does not override abstract method getfirst() in IBlocks*. It seems that it does not even recognize that the @Override is there, when I take it out it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I could be off-base with this but, I believe with your method header it is asking to have a Resting returned.  Is there any way you can create a boolean object and have that returned? maybe name it something like empty and if it is empty it returns true and if it is not empty it returns false?  Another suggestion would be to manually set Resting to 0 if it meets the criteria for being set to zero such as if (condition is met) { returnedResting = 0; }.